# Magnifying glasses

Tags: microscopy

In very simple terms, I understand that magnification occurs when light refracts through a biconvex lense producing a larger image on our retinas.  But why is there no magnification if the object is right against the lense?  Isn't the light still refacting at the same angles?

Comment: You can use Google to find an answer to this question.  Just go to google.com, and type in, "how a magnifying glass works."

Answer (score 0):

Magnifying glasses work by giving the eye a sharp image at a distance that is too close for the unaided eye. The standard near-limit for a human is 25 cm. With a loupe, one can put the object at the focal point of the lens instead (or even a bit closer) and still see a focused image. That is why the magnification factor is given as 25 cm divided by the focal length. It is the angular magnification, the ratio $\alpha'/\alpha$ in this figure:
[image]